# generics: 'Unchecked assignment' warning

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

My code:

```
class Pattern
  {
  private Vector<Category>[] mCategories;

  private class Category
    {
    // ...
    }

  public Pattern(int numCat)
    {
    mCategories = new Vector[numCat];   // <-- Here I get the warning
    }
  }
```

IntelliJ gives me a warning

**'Unchecked assignment': java.util.Vector[] to 'java.util.Vector<my.package.Pattern.Category>[]'**

making it

```
mCategories = new Vector<>[numCat];
```

not only doesn't help, but gives me an error **'Cannot infer arguments'**

So how do I solve this?

Comment: The best option is to not use an array. Arrays and generics do not mix well.

Comment: Well, yes, the problem is though - the real number of categories is not 4 - I just wrote 4 here for brevity. The number depends on runtime data. Question edited for clarity :)

Comment: Not sure how that prevents you from using a `List<List<Category>>`?

Comment: Well, yes, you're right :)